# Characteristic Polynomial (Give an example)

Tags: linear-algebra

**Question:** Give an example of a matrix which is not diagonalizable but whose characteristic polynomial can be written as a product of degree 1 polynomials.

This is a question on one of my past exam papers and I just have no idea what it entails. I know what diagonalizable means and the characteristic polynomial but I have no idea what the question here is even asking me to find.

Does it have anything to do with the Cayley-Hamilton theorem?

Answer (score 1):

The matrix $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ has characteristic polynomial $(1-\lambda)^2$, which is a product of linear factors, but it is not diagonalizable.

Answer (score 0):

thanks very much for replying so quickly and I like that you didn't answer it straight away. I had to chance to look up shear online and I found a lot of useful information.

The characteristic polynomial of a horizontal shear transformation is $(\lambda - 1)^{2}$

A horizontal shear matrix was given by $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & k \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Can I put any value in for k and it will still not be diagonalizable. You put in the value 1, could I just replace that with any number?

Comment: For each $k$ the eigenspace for the eigenvalue 1 has the dimension 1. Thus, there is no basis of $ \mathbb R^2$, which consists of eigenvectors of your matrix. Thus: for each $k$ your matrix is not  diagonalizable.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you.